# Condição IF em javascript só funciona uma vez

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, if

Estou tentando fazer um `Side Navigation`, então em pesquisa na internet, achei um tutorialzinho no site: [How TO - Side Navigation](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp)

Porém, no meu exemplo queria que um unico botão abrisse, e fechasse, então fiz as seguintes modificações:

```
function closeNav()
{    
    if (document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width < 250)
    {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "40px";
    }  
}
```

Mas, ele so funciona uma vez, ou seja, ele abre e fecha depois não funciona mais.

Comment: Onde é que tem Java aí?

Comment: Você pode fazer um exemplo no JSFiddle?

Comment: Nunca faça a side-nav aparecer e desaparecer através da alteração do width, use o css translateX do transform. Quando você faz a alteração da width você gera vários Paints custosos que são feitos pela CPU, se você usar translateX você terá Paints extremamente leves executados pela GPU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O valor que `.style.width` retorna é uma *string*. Tens de usar um conversor de tipo para teres um numero e usar o operador `<`.

Podias fazer isso assim:

```
function closeNav() {
    var sideNav = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
    if (parseInt(sideNav.style.width) < 250) {
        sideNav.style.width = "250px";
    } else {
        sideNav.style.width = "40px";
    }
}
```

Comment: Amigo, funcionou perfeitamente, porém, para funcionar a primeira vez, tenho que clicar duas vezes. sabe o porque?

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel provavelmente porque esse elemento `#mySidenav` não tem um estilo definido de inicio. Somente no CSS não vai ser lido pelo `.style.width`. Testa colocar `style="width: ..."` no HTML. Se tiver percebido mal faz um jsFiddle para ser mais claro.